# Bitcoins stuck in memory pool

Tags: mining-pools, unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-verification, mempool, lost-bitcoins

I sent my `0.1 bitcoin` on the 8th of January from an offline wallet (Bitcoin Core), to an online wallet. Still haven't got the btc in my new wallet. The status on the offline wallet says: `"unconfirmed, in memory pool"`. When I paste the TX ID in the Blockchain it won't give any results. Has this happend to anyone else? If so, do you know how to fix it, or how long it takes before the BTC gets out of the memory pool?

Also, when I sent the `0.1 bitcoin`, at first the offline wallet wouldn't let me send it because I didn't have enough transaction fee in my wallet. (I had `0.1 btc` in my wallet) So I sent `0.09995520 btc` which was exactly enough for my remaining btc to cover the transaction fees. So I don't think it's because of the transaction fees that my btc is now stuck in memory pool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "offline wallet"? If the sending wallet is truly not connected to the internet and no other steps have been undertaken to submit the transaction to the Bitcoin network, I would have an outlandish theory why the Bitcoin network hasn't become aware of the transaction. ;)